# Question of using ruby on rails in an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, windows-phone-7, rss

My ruby on rails knowledge is gaining (i'm reading tutorials and books) but I have a problem grasping one element of Ruby and Ruby on Rails, concerning my domain web page and web services.

Some background:

I have a web page I'm creating in dreamweaver which I ftp to my web domain. My design is to have my web page look like a blogging website, where I post a single picture up at a time for people to view. I want to have it set up that every time I upload an image to my domain, ruby gets the html of that, and every specific image of this nature, and throws it to a web service for people who use windows phone 7 to have update in an app I am making.

My question stems from a lack of Ruby knowledge. I don't want to make my webpage some gigantic ruby application, but instead I just want Ruby to know when I place an image, to get the html link, and to send that information out.

Does ruby identify this automatically? Do I have to run my server for the changes to be found by ruby and to send them out?

I want to send the image url through either XML or Json, and am in dire need of sample code to get this accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation sounds like a perfect use case for RSS. There are many ways to set up an RSS feed and each one will depend on how your current site is set up.

Comment: I was indeed considering RSS, and I love everything about it. However I am uncertain as to how I can incorporate an RSS feed based on the domain's hosting capabilities. They gave me Wordpress, Ruby, Ruby on Rails, PHP, and MySQL. However, while I know Wordpress has a built in RSS feeder, I don't want to use it. Is there a way to incorporate an RSS feed into this equation?

Comment: and by, "I don't want to use it," I mean Wordpress.

Comment: Give this a shot (you are using dreamweaver, right?): http://www.dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/dreamweaver/articles/rss-feed-dreamweaver.htm

Comment: thank you very much and I will definitely look into that. Have any of you ever been overwhelmed by learning new stuff? Yeah, I'm that * not knowing what i'm doing nor talking about :).  Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Excellent. RSS feed active. Now just need to get it consumed!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I definitely understand that overwhelming feeling - the trick is to just keep immersing yourself in it - eventually it all starts to come together. Good luck!